# Check if $NP ⊆ BPP $

Tags: complexity-theory

Check if $NP ⊆ BPP $
I know that if $NP ⊆ BPP $ then $NP=RP$, which is not known fact. So, we don't know if $NP ⊆ BPP$.
Maybe some other explanation of this exercise ?

Comment: You keep posting solved exercises. We don't check solutions here.

Comment: yes, I would like another solution - what highlighted. Simply in educational aims :) Thanks :)